# Variance of an observation of an arbitrary state measured consecutively by two operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

If A and B are two commuting observables, and the observable A is first measured on an arbitrary state, and then B is measured on the resultant state, what is the variance in the last observation?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, what work have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I need some clarification on the phrase "variance of the last observation"... Variance is typically defined for operators in quantum mechanics, so I don't understand what variance of an observation means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are commuting observables, we can express a general state $|\Psi \rangle$ as a superposition of simultaneous eigenstates of $A$ and $B$. In other words, we can say that
\begin{equation}
| \Psi \rangle = \sum_{a,b} c_{a,b} |a\rangle | b \rangle
\end{equation}
where $c_{a,b}$ are complex coefficients, $|a\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$ ($A | a \rangle = a | a \rangle$), and $|b\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $B$ with eigenvalue $b$ ($B | b \rangle = b | b \rangle$). I'll take the states to be normalized so that $\langle a | a' \rangle =\delta_{a,a'}$ and $\langle b | b' \rangle = \delta_{b,b'}$.

The variance of $B$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma_B^2 &=& \langle \Psi | B^2 | \Psi \rangle - |\langle \Psi | B | \Psi \rangle |^2 \nonumber \\
&=&  \sum_{a,b} b^2 |c_{a,b}|^2 - \left|\sum_{a,b} b |c_{a,b}|^2 \right|^2
\end{eqnarray}

If you measured $A$ to have a definite value $a_\star$, then we can define $c_b \equiv c_{a_\star,b}$, and the above expression becomes

\begin{equation}
\sigma_B^2 = \sum_{b} b^2 |c_{b}|^2 - \left|\sum_{b} b |c_{b}|^2 \right|^2
\end{equation}

That's the best you can do without knowing the state exactly. One important special case is if the system is in an eigenstate of $B$. Then $|c_b|=1$ and the variance is zero.

Comment: I believe there might be some mistake in the second line in te expression for variance. I don't know what steps you took, but this doesn't seem to hold. Take $B = \sigma_z$, for example, and consider $\vert \psi \rangle = (\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle)/ \sqrt{2}$. The variance should be 1 (one can check this in the first line), but the second line doesn't give this result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! My confusion was the last part of the question: "variance in the last observation", which as you have pointed out, is just the variance in B since it's the last operator to act on the state.

Comment: @LucasBaldo You are right! That's what I get for answering before coffee. I think it should be fixed now (it works for the example you gave), but of course if you spot any more errors let me know! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I believe your answer is spot on, now, Andrew :) . I would also stress, @Sacredmechanic1, that the operatos are what we measure. For this reason, physicist tend to use "observables", "observation" and "operators" interchangeably.